# REST (json) web service discovery protocol

Tags: web-services, json, rest

Is there any json-only standard to handle resource discovery (ie. collections of editable entries) ?

I mean some "protocol" to use in a self-describing REST service, eventually with hypermedia discovery (read, links and paging)

What about some Atom Publishing Protocol json equivalent ?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can use something like this: http://restdesc.org/

Comment: looks interesting but very poorly documented

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you should have a look at [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) (which works with JSON-LD). If you find it interesting, there's a Hydra W3C Community Group you may wanna join.

Here's the recording of a talk in which I describe both Hydra and JSON-LD: [Building Next-Generation Web APIs with JSON-LD and Hydra](http://bit.ly/sl-portland2013-video)

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Hydra and the chair of the Hydra CG. I'm also one of the core designers of JSON-LD and a co-author and editor of its specifications.*

Comment: Can you summarize, *in your answer,* the benefits that Hydra provides?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could take a look at JSON-LD:
http://json-ld.org/

Answer (score -1):

A protocol? The whole point of REST is that you just ask a resource for a representation that happens to contain links to other resources. Pretty much any resource can tell you about other resources that happen to be relevant. There isn't a protocol specifically for discovery precisely because discovery is built into the whole architecture.

Some RESTful services publish service descriptions in a format like WADL, which could allow a client to predict the URIs for the some of the sorts of resources that the service provides. But that's not a substitute for actually getting links from other resources published by the service, as those links are concrete whereas WADL talks about URI templates.

Comment: The question is about a standard/consolidated technology (vs a custom solution) to "put discovery into the whole architecture", ie. links representation. WADL is XML and does not provide content but only the service description. AtomPub instead does transport content __with__ its (meta) description, moreover it handles hypermedia (but is still XML :)